# Iterating through a merge sorted list

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort

Here is my problem:

> Assume the days of the current year are numbered 1 to 365. A Coverage is defined as a range of dates with a coverage start and end/term date. Eg: `Cov(1, 31)` means the person is covered for something for Jan of this year.
>
> Problem: Given a series of coverage data for a person, we need to find the longest continuous coverage. The coverage may have overlap and/or gaps in coverage. (Given code is in Scala, I used Java to solve).
>
> ```
> class Cov(eff: Int, term: Int)
>     val coverages = List(Cov(1,20), Cov(21,30), Cov(15,25), Cov(28,40), Cov(50, 60), Cov(61,200))
> ```

I could be approaching this question all wrong but I wanted to use mergesort to sort the original array, and then iterate through it, to print the longest term. My mergesort sorts my list. Which is what I wanted. But I am having trouble with how to move on to finding the longest continuous coverage. It wouldn't be just be printing the last index and 2nd to last index so I am lost.

```scala
public class Cov {

    private int eff;
    private int term;

    public Cov(int eff, int term) {
        this.eff = eff;
        this.term = term;
    }

    public static void merge(int[] coverage, int eff, int mid, int term) {
        // Creating temporary subarrays
        int leftArray[] = new int[mid - eff + 1];
        int rightArray[] = new int[term - mid];

        // Copying our subarrays into temporaries
        for (int i = 0; i < leftArray.length; i++)
            leftArray[i] = coverage[eff + i];
        for (int i = 0; i < rightArray.length; i++)
            rightArray[i] = coverage[mid + i + 1];

        // Iterators containing current index of temp subarrays
        int leftIndex = 0;
        int rightIndex = 0;

        // Copying from leftArray and rightArray back into array
        for (int i = eff; i < term + 1; i++) {
            // If there are still uncopied elements in R and L, copy minimum of the two
            if (leftIndex < leftArray.length && rightIndex < rightArray.length) {
                if (leftArray[leftIndex] < rightArray[rightIndex]) {
                   coverage[i] = leftArray[leftIndex];
                   leftIndex++;
                } else {
                    coverage[i] = rightArray[rightIndex];
                    rightIndex++;
                }
            } else if (leftIndex < leftArray.length) {
                // If all elements have been copied from rightArray, copy rest of leftArray
                coverage[i] = leftArray[leftIndex];
                leftIndex++;
            } else if (rightIndex < rightArray.length) {
                // If all elements have been copied from leftArray, copy rest of rightArray
                coverage[i] = rightArray[rightIndex];
                rightIndex++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void mergeSort(int[] coverage, int eff, int term) {
        if (term <= eff) return;

        int mid = (eff + term) / 2;
        mergeSort(coverage, eff, mid);
        mergeSort(coverage, mid + 1, term);
        merge(coverage, eff, mid, term);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> coverages = new ArrayList<>();
        int coverage[] = { 1, 20, 21, 30, 15, 25, 28, 40, 50, 60, 61, 200 };
        merge(coverage, 0, 5, 11);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(coverage));

            for (int i = 0; i < coverage.length - 1; i++) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why use homegrown merge-sort and not just the built-in [`Arrays.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-) or [`Collections.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)?

Comment: I'll be honest, I forgot Java had these built-in sort classes until you just mentioned it.

Comment: Welp. Now I feel silly. I just did all that for no reason. But I am still stuck on this longest continuous tenure part

Comment: How is `61,200` a `start and end/term date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find longest continued coverage, iterate the list and keep track of current coverage period, extending/replacing as needed.

```
var coverages = List.of(new Cov(1,20), new Cov(21,30), new Cov(15,25),
        new Cov(28,40), new Cov(50, 60), new Cov(61,200));

// Sort coverage periods by start value (eff)
//   (streaming into new list since original list is immutable)
coverages = coverages.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Cov::getEff))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Iterate coverage periods and find length of longest continuously covered period
int currEff = -1, currTerm = -1, maxLen = 0;
for (Cov cov : coverages) {
    if (cov.getEff() > currTerm + 1) { // Replace current coverage period if gap detected
        currEff = cov.getEff();
        currTerm = cov.getTerm();
    } else if (currTerm < cov.getTerm()) { // Extend current coverage period if needed
        currTerm = cov.getTerm();
    }
    // Update max if current coverage period is longer than any seen so far
    if (currTerm - currEff >= maxLen)
        maxLen = currTerm - currEff + 1;
}

System.out.println(maxLen); // prints: 151
```

```
class Cov {
    private final int eff;
    private final int term;
    public Cov(int eff, int term) {
        this.eff = eff;
        this.term = term;
    }
    public int getEff() {
        return this.eff;
    }
    public int getTerm() {
        return this.term;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cov(" + this.eff + "," + this.term + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Andreas. Much appreciated. Question, is the var for coverages in the main method supposed to be a var? What data type is that since it won't let me compile cause of that line.

Comment: @bstapies `var` "keyword" was added in Java 10. See [JEP 286: Local-Variable Type Inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286) --- Replace `var` with `List<Cov>` if using Java < 10. Just wanted to make it look as close as possible to your Scala code. 

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you. @Andreas I see. Thanks

Comment: *FYI:* `List.of(...)` was added in Java 9.

Comment: I reverted it back to < Java10 and I am getting an error at "List.of". It says "The method of (Cov, Cov, Cov, Cov, Cov) is undefined for type list" . I'm unfamiliar with the "List.of" notation. I think I am running on 1.8. What would it be for that?

Comment: @bstapies Use `Arrays.asList(...)`